# Adapting jquery to slide div as opposed to window.scrollX - sliding the entire window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this current setup and I need to change it so that only the images move to the left/right when the input prev/next buttons are clicked, the rest of the my site represented by the header at the top of the fiddle needs to not move to the right with the images.

In the jquery I've got window.scrollX but I essentially need to only allow the div '#imageWrapper' to move, leaving the rest of my site where it should be. I'm not great with jquery so if anyone could help with what I need that would be great..

Please see my jsfiddle to see what I require.

Can anyone help?

Here is my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/s2TJQ/441/

```
$(function() {
    var boxLefts = [];
    $('.images').each(function(i, el) {
        boxLefts.push(this.offsetLeft);
    });
    $("input").click(function(e) {
        var dir = false,
            targetLeft = -1;

        var target = e.target.className;
        if (target == 'next') {
            dir = 1;
        } else {
            dir = -1;
        }
        if (dir) {
            e.preventDefault();
            winLeft = window.scrollX;
            $.each(boxLefts, function(i, v) {
                if ((dir == 1 && winLeft < v && targetLeft < 0) || (dir == -1 && winLeft > v)) {
                    targetLeft = v;
                }
            });
            if (targetLeft >= 0) {
                $('html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)').stop().animate({
                    scrollLeft: targetLeft
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use ```position: fixed``` for siteContent.

Comment: Thanks for your response - siteContent represents the whole of my webpage so is there not a way I could change the jquery to move only the div:imageWrapper instead of the whole window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look to my Demo please!

http://jsfiddle.net/s2TJQ/443/

i changed the css of:

**#imageWrapper** + `margin-top: 105px;`

**.siteContent** +

```
margin-bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
```

**UPDATE:** AS PER YOUR COMMENT, I CHANGED MANY THINGS IN YOUR CODE!
try this Demo and let me knowif it works as  you would like!
http://jsfiddle.net/s2TJQ/446/

NOTE: where and when to stop sliding is still missed!

Comment: Thanks for your response - siteContent represents the whole of my webpage so is there not a way I could change the jquery to move only the div:imageWrapper instead of the whole window

Comment: @user2498890, your goal is to have an images slider with next and prev buttons? and it slides only on click events? is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @user2498890: i updated my answer, try it please. i have no ipad so i cannot test it now!

Comment: Thats nearly what I need but the images will be 2 showing on a page at once so I'm working at 1440px and images are 720px each so I need it to move one whole image in at a time, at the moment the fiddle just moves little distances. Also how do I get rid of all the whitespace either side of the four images? Ideally I'd like to get to the end and then it jump back to the first image? Thanks for your help, your awesome!

Comment: Also I need the image to have height auto for responsive purposes? But the height on the div.slider is set to 200px and if i change it to auto it doesn't work...

Comment: @user2498890: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59743/discussion-between-rami-q-and-user2498890).